# sending email from spring app using godaddy

Tags: spring, email

Hi i'm trying to send mail from my spring boot app using godaddy email.
I have purchase the domain name and email id .Now i want to send mail from that domain, but it showing some errors.

```
public boolean sendMail(String to, String subject, String content) {
        String from = "info@mydomain.com";
        String password ="***********";
        try {
              Properties props = System.getProperties();
              props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
              props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtpout.mydomain.com");

             props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true" );
             props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
             props.setProperty("mail.user", from);
             props.setProperty("mail.password", password);

            Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            // mailSession.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            message.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setContent(content, "text/html");
            transport.connect("smtpout.mydomain.com",from,password);
            transport.sendMessage(message,
             message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return false;
    }
```

Errors:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtpout.mydomain.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Maybe your credentials are incorrect or the propert `props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtpout.mydomain.com");`. Maybe you misspelled.

Comment: No the credentials are correct.

Comment: What about the above `mail.host, smtpout...` property? Is that correct? Also can you try with this Example - https://github.com/RawSanj/java-mail-clients/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rawsanj/mail/SendGMailTLS.java

Comment: Do you have any example for custom domain ..for example domain purchased from GoDaddy.

Comment: Nope. but I think that should work. You just need to configure the host and all correctly.